# Taking a neutral wire from another meter connection?

Tags: electrical, meter, neutral

I live in a two story duplex, yesterday the other unit's electricity went off, the electrician diagnosed that somehow their neutral path is not coming from the pole so he connected the neutral connection from my meter to their neutral (changing some wires through circuit breaker). He was doing it through circuit breakers as we don't have a main breaker.
 So my question is "with the live wire from his meter but a neutral path through my meter, is my meter is being used?"

Comment: I _believe_ you're OK -- remembef, the neutal is bonded to ground at the box, so there is no "neutral from the transformer" per se; both neutrals, both grounds, and the center tap of the transformer should all be connected direvtly to earth.  But I'm not certain, and I'm not convinced this meets code.

Comment: This connection was made on your side of the meter? Is it a temporary hack, or does he plan to leave it like that? I'd contact the utility, and explain the situation. If there's a dropped service neutral, the utility should fix it. I don't think the utility would be very fond of this setup, as it will likely mess up billing, and potentially overload your neutral.

Comment: Instead of doing what he did he should have called the utility. Sounds like it could be, or is, on their side. They do work weekends.

Comment: it sounds like it is now possible to overload the single working neutral

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR: CALL YOUR ELECTRIC UTILITY ON THEIR EMERGENCY NUMBER

It sounds like you live in a duplex with dual services -- in that case, call your utility ASAP.  What the electrician did was a *very* dirty hack that will not pass Code muster, and likely screw with the electrical metering -- it will also break in interesting ways if later on the utility puts the two units on different transformer secondaries.

BTW -- an open neutral is an *emergency* situation, as it can easily be a fire and/or shock hazard.

Answer (score 0):

If the terminal on the meter for the neutral that was joined with your  neutral is the outgoing terminal, then your meter if smart will read the reaulting current from your neutral and his neutral. If he has more load than you and he uses single phase, then your meter will read very fast.  But if it was joined in the incoming neutral terminal, then your meter will not read his neutral energy.

Abdullahi Yahaya

Comment: This could be weirder still, depending on what electrical system is in use...